# Easy way to work with Camera in Android

Tags: android, camera

Currently I'm developing an Android app that deals a lot with taking pictures.
I used the native camera with intents before, but now I have to style the camera preview with custom buttons and a custom layout.
I'm looking for a simple view that can display a live camera preview.

Such a view doesn't seem to exist without a lot of overhead. There's a lot of confusion about the surfaceView & TextureView it seems.
I started looking for a decent library, but only found this:
https://github.com/Glamdring/EasyCamera
and so far I can't seem to get this to work, there is no example here either.

How do you guys tackle this? It seems that the common way to work with a camera preview is way to complicated and there are no decent libraries yet?
Please point me in the right direction. :)

Is everybody using the native camera or is everybody in pain? ;-)